# Google Analytics v3 doesn't show real time data

Tags: android, google-analytics, real-time

I followed very carefully after next instructions:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/

I see some events in log, but still can't get real time data

(This is how I can ensure the analytics works)

**Stack trace:**

```
921    4319-4319/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]: [EasyTracker] sample rate loaded: 100.0
09-09 08:26:57.931    4319-4319/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]:     [EasyTracker] dispatch period loaded: 1800
09-09 08:26:57.931    4319-4319/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]: Dispatch period set with null handler. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete.
09-09 08:26:57.931    4319-4319/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]: [EasyTracker] session timeout loaded: 30000
09-09 08:26:57.931    4319-4319/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]: [EasyTracker] auto activity tracking loaded: true
09-09 08:26:57.931    4319-4319/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]:  ExceptionReporter created, original handler is   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler
09-09 08:26:57.931    4319-4319/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[main,5,main]: [EasyTracker] report uncaught exceptions loaded: true
09-09 08:26:58.001    4319-4319/com.company.appname D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
09-09 08:26:58.001    4319-4319/com.company.appname D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
09-09 08:26:58.001    4319-4319/com.company.appname D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
09-09 08:26:58.011    4319-4319/com.company.appname I/Adreno200-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: Iabe52cfaeae4c5fab1acacfe6f056ba15fa93274
09-09 08:26:58.041    4319-4319/com.company.appname D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
09-09 08:26:58.101      607-624/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.company.appname/.activities.SplashActivity: +403ms
09-09 08:27:02.917    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
09-09 08:27:02.927    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) }
09-09 08:27:02.927    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
09-09 08:27:02.927    4319-4336/com.company.appname I/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
09-09 08:27:02.937    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
09-09 08:27:05.910    4319-4346/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[Failed Connect,5,main]: falling back to local store
09-09 08:27:05.930    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store  PATH: https:  PARAMS: v=1,  ul=en-us,  t=appview,  ht=1378704417947,  sr=768x1184,  an=appname,  sc=start,  tid=UA-30287113-8,  aid=com.company.appname,  cid=0d844bff-617e-4a52-8012-0d2777478ff7,  av=3.2,  _u=.K28,  cd=com.company.appname.activities.SplashActivity,
09-09 08:27:05.940    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode initiated.
09-09 08:27:05.960    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode terminated.
09-09 08:27:05.960    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Dispatch running...
09-09 08:27:05.970    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/3.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-us; Nexus 4 Build/JWR66V)
    Host: ssl.google-analytics.com
    GET /collect?ul=en-us&ht=1378704417947&sr=768x1184&sc=start&aid=com.company.appname&cid=0d000bff-617e-4a52-8012-0d2000478ff7&av=3.2&v=1&t=appview&an=appname&tid=UA-30000000-8&_u=.K28&_v=ma3.0.0&cd=com.company.appname.activities.SplashActivity&qt=8030&z=26 HTTP/1.1
09-09 08:27:06.530    4319-4336/com.company.appname D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 311K, 3% free 11897K/12232K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
09-09 08:27:07.091    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: sent 1 of 1 hits
09-09 08:27:07.101    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode initiated.
09-09 08:27:07.101    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
09-09 08:27:07.101    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store  PATH: https:  PARAMS: v=1,  ul=en-us,  t=appview,  ht=1378704426546,  sr=768x1184,  an=appname,  tid=UA-30287113-8,  aid=com.company.appname,  cid=0d844bff-617e-4a52-8012-0d2777478ff7,  av=3.2,  _u=.9rs38,  cd=com.company.appname.activities.SplashActivity,
09-09 08:27:07.111    4319-4336/com.company.appname V/GAV3: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode terminated.
```

**UPDATE:**

The analytics works, but not the real time data

Comment: your APK package seems to be: com.company.appname.  Is that what you are looking for on the GA site?

Comment: @larham1 It's ok. I changed it here to `com.company.appname` for privacy.

Comment: as part of the GA info sent up, there's the "tid", the package name. Could Google be filtering on that?  i.e., you're sending up "com.company.appname" and it is looking for something else?  Or did you just change it for posting on SO?

Comment: fyi, I have the same problem. A test app succeeds in making real-time hits show up on GA when using v1.5.1 of the GA library for Android. Same app fails with libraries V2b5 and V3.0 so far. The failures show debug logging of dispatch to ssl.google-analytics.com/collect. I'm investigating...

Comment: I had the same problem, but I solved it by using a mobile app profile (not Universal!!), although real time hits are showed on the GA site after almost one minute (dispatch period is 2 sec). Another strange thing is that my logs are different than yours, and I cannot understand why. Example: instead of `sending hit to store` I have `sending hit to service` and no power save messages. Any ideas?

Comment: Why is the Universal profile not working. It is the intention to have all device types reported in one "universal" property right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention before in comments:

1. To work with Google Analytics V3 in mobile,

   You have to use a mobile app profile (make a new one),
   and not the one you already have.
2. Real time data comes, but it can take 1-4 min. Patience please.